# Sanitize HTML with HtmlEscape, only < and >

Tags: dart

I'm having trouble with escaping HTML using `HtmlEscape` in `dart:convert`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

var sanitizer = new HtmlEscape(HtmlEscapeMode.ELEMENT);
var text = 'http://woven.co/';

print(text);
text = sanitizer.convert(text);
print(text); // http:&#x2F;&#x2F;woven.co&#x2F;
```

Try it at: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6036b7f888128b310a78

I expected the string not to change, given the `HtmlEscapeMode.ELEMENT` definition:
https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert.HtmlEscapeMode#id_ELEMENT

As well, for the life of me I can't figure out how to pass my own `HtmlEscapeMode` in.

Comment: I feel like dartpad is using and old dart version.

Comment: Well, I've got 1.10 on my local, and same thing.

Answer (score 2):

When I run the following code in the latest dev version (1.10.0-dev.1.10) I get the desired result. I guess dartpad uses and old version of dart.

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var sanitizer = new HtmlEscape(HtmlEscapeMode.ELEMENT);
  var text = 'http://woven.co/';

  print(text);
  text = sanitizer.convert(text);
  print(text);
}
```

> http://woven.co/
>   http://woven.co/

Comment: Hm, I've got 1.10. I imagine DartPad also using that latest stable version.

Comment: dartpad does not complete for `SQ_ELEMENT` mode thus I don't think they use the latest stable version.

Comment: Weird. In a brand new test.dart, it works as expected. But the same exact code in my app printed to console, does not work.

Comment: Yes, that's really strange. Too bad there is no sdk-version over at dartpad.

Comment: There were definitely _some_ changes to `HtmlEscape` in 1.10, see [release notes](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/announce/l-wQTHX3VJo) (Edit: Oops, should always expand comments before posting!)

Comment: I raised an issue suggesting they add the version to DartPad: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/403

Comment: There's something more going on than the SDK version over at DartPad. I opened a new issue here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23400&thanks=23400&ts=1430924595